# sympy solve equation set: results in error: only zero-dimensional systems supported

Tags: python, sympy, equation

i want to calculate the steady states of a set of differential equations, as you can see in the following code.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import solve
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing()

X = Symbol("\X")
Y = Symbol("\Y")
Z = Symbol("\Z")

tau = Symbol(r"\tau")

Ryx = Symbol(r"\Ryx")
Rxy = Symbol(r"\Rxy")
Ry    = Symbol(r"\Ry")
Rz    = Symbol(r"\Rz")
Rzy    = Symbol(r"\Rzy")
Rzz    = Symbol(r"\Rzz")
Rxz    = Symbol(r"\Rxz")
Ryz    = Symbol(r"\Ryz")

#equation system
dX = X - X**2 - Ryx * Y * X
dY = Ry * ( Y - Y**2 + Rxy * X * Y + Rzy * Z * Y )
dZ = Rz * ( -Rzz * Z + Rxz * X * Z + Ryz * Y * Z )
equilibria = solve( (dX,dY,dZ),X,Y,Z )
```

If I copy my code in the sympy live shell the code works fine and gives me my set of solutions.

As I want to  save my results in a latex file, I want to run this code on my system. Which is the following Ubuntu 12.04, python2.7.3, sympy 0.7.1. 
Here my code results in the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: only zero-dimensional systems supported (finite number of solutions)
```

If I cancel out the last equation and the Z variable I get a set of solutions

```
equilibria = solve( (dX,dY),X,Y )
-> [(0, 0), (1, 0)]
```

In my opinion, the system needs to much computation time to solve the complete set.

Do you have any suggestions?

I found the module which might solve this problem

```
 from sympy.solvers.solveset import nonlinsolve
```

But my version of sympy doesn't know this module.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try updating Sympy to the latest version (1.0)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not working with my computer, so I'm not allowed to upgrade my Ubuntu system (12.04) and 0.7.1 is the latest version at 12.04

Comment: @AlexanderTille you can install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which comes with SymPy. It does not require root permissions and it installs to your home directory.

Comment: Well it worked with Anaconda. Thank you very much!